# jqGrid Time Management/Calendar Processor Development

Tags: php, jqgrid, calendar

I'm working with jqGrid to develop a time management module for a customer. We have already deployed jqGrid extensively over the rest of the site so we're working to make it fit this role too.

We need to be able to display a column for each day of a calendar month, each day then being split into two columns for overtime worked (HV - text input box) and the reason (R - select dropdown). I've got the grid designed to an extent (overtime/reason columns, list of branch staff etc) but am having trouble writing the processor. The code below shows what I currently have. This populates the grid (via another file) with a list of employees. The column list (day numbers 1-31) is generated from a PHP function which determines the current month and year. Grid.php then posts to gridsave.php when the row is clicked-off.

I would like to be able to determine which field has been edited as easily as possible. I do not want 62 columns (HV and R for each day of a 31 day month) in my database just in case, I'd like to programmatically determine the field id (date) and store that in a date column using my processor. If at all possible, I'd like to only pass modified fields to my processor to save on processing time.

Then, in reverse, I need to be able to extract this information (based on the date determined above) and input it into the correct column in jqGrid.

Needless to say I've now come up against a brick wall and not sure how to proceed on any of the above so will have to bow to superior knowledge. Any assistance in this will be much appreciated!

grid.php

```
    var lastsel2;
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
      jQuery("#timeLog").jqGrid({
        url:'datagrid.php?module=timemanagement&branchid=<?php echo($branchid); ?>',
        editurl: "gridsave.php?branchid=<?php echo($branchid); ?>",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['First Name','Surname','Job Title',       
        <?php
        $x = 1;
        while($x <= $numdays) {
            echo("'HV',");
            echo("'R',");
            $x++;
        }           
        ?>
        ],
        colModel :[ 
            {name:'firstname', index:'firstname', align: 'center', width: 100, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'cn', 'nc']}}, 
            {name:'lastname', index:'lastname', align: 'center', width: 100, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'cn', 'nc']}},
            {name:'jobtitle', index:'jobtitle', align: 'center', width: 100, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'cn', 'nc']}},
            <?php
            $x = 1;
            while($x <= $numdays) {
                echo("{name:'hv-$x-$month-$year', index:'hv', align: 'center', width: 25, sortable: false, editable: true},");
                echo("{name:'r-$x-$month-$year', index:'r', align: 'center', width: 25, sortable: false, editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions:{value:':;OT:OT;S:S;H:H;OA:OA'}},");
                $x++;
            }
            ?>
        ],
        onSelectRow: function(id){
            if(id && id!==lastsel2){
                $('#timeLog').jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel2);
                $('#timeLog').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
                lastsel2=id;
            }
        },
        pager: '#pager',
        height: 500,
        rowNum:25,
        rowList:[25,50,100],
        sortname: 'firstname',
        sortorder: 'ASC',
        viewrecords: true,
      }).navGrid('#pager', {search:true, edit: false, add:false, del:false});
    });
```

gridsave.php

```
// Check for exec permission
define('_CHECKEXEC', TRUE);

// Connect to database
include("./includes/init.inc.php");

if($_GET['oper'] == "edit") {
    // Generate query and insert data
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbltimemanagement(userid, hv, r) VALUES ('$_POST[id]', '$_POST[hv]', '$_POST[r]');";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: I see mayor security issues here !! NEVER EVER trust user INPUT, allowing post data directly in a query is bad practice. read this : [link](http://members.ii.net/~a.koepke/never-trust-user-data.html)

Comment: I do appreciate your comments, perhaps I should have mentioned this is nowhere near production yet, I'm trying to prove if it will work in theory before putting lots of time into it then having to scrap it and start again.. I'll deal with validation when my finger is no longer hovering over the delete and start again button!

Comment: A good start, will get you halfway there. leaving these 'small' issues, might cause big broblems further on. Once the script is working the chance you or your collegues open the file again is pretty small. but in the end, always be carefull with user input! Post data can easily be transformed with simple browser plugins.